# Accurate eye tracker to move the mouse cursor supporting multi-monitors

Tags: mice, eye-tracker

I am looking for an accurate eye tracker (a.k.a. eye tracking device) to move the mouse cursor supporting multi-monitors (6 to be precise). [Tobii EyeX Controller](http://www.tobii.com/en/eye-experience/) only supports one monitor as far as I know. It should be compatible with Microsoft Windows and if possible Linux.

Comment: Even with the new 4C still seems to be a no?

Comment: @JMY1000 That's correct. 4C: "Works on single screen set up, max screen size 27" 16:9 or 30" 21:9."